# How can I change offset jquery option on Slider Revolution depending on width screen

Tags: jquery, offset, revolution-slider

The problem I’m facing, I need to set a vertical offset (this can be set in the panel of the plugin), but I want it only on certain screen sizes, because my header is vertical on large screen an horizontal when small size, so the offset is needed only on small sizes.

On bigger width than 1100px I need and offet of 0px, but on smaller i need an offset of 125px;

Here is the script that initiate the plugin with the desire options, and the one that I need in order to change the offset is this one **fullScreenOffset**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                /******************************************
        -   PREPARE PLACEHOLDER FOR SLIDER  -
    ******************************************/

    var setREVStartSize=function(){
        try{var e=new Object,i=jQuery(window).width(),t=9999,r=0,n=0,l=0,f=0,s=0,h=0;
            e.c = jQuery('#rev_slider_2_1');
            e.responsiveLevels = [1240,1024,778,480];
            e.gridwidth = [1400,1240,778,480];
            e.gridheight = [868,768,960,720];

            e.sliderLayout = "fullscreen";
            e.fullScreenAutoWidth='on';
            e.fullScreenAlignForce='off';
            e.fullScreenOffsetContainer= '';
            e.fullScreenOffset='';
            if(e.responsiveLevels&&(jQuery.each(e.responsiveLevels,function(e,f){f>i&&(t=r=f,l=e),i>f&&f>r&&(r=f,n=e)}),t>r&&(l=n)),f=e.gridheight[l]||e.gridheight[0]||e.gridheight,s=e.gridwidth[l]||e.gridwidth[0]||e.gridwidth,h=i/s,h=h>1?1:h,f=Math.round(h*f),"fullscreen"==e.sliderLayout){var u=(e.c.width(),jQuery(window).height());if(void 0!=e.fullScreenOffsetContainer){var c=e.fullScreenOffsetContainer.split(",");if (c) jQuery.each(c,function(e,i){u=jQuery(i).length>0?u-jQuery(i).outerHeight(!0):u}),e.fullScreenOffset.split("%").length>1&&void 0!=e.fullScreenOffset&&e.fullScreenOffset.length>0?u-=jQuery(window).height()*parseInt(e.fullScreenOffset,0)/100:void 0!=e.fullScreenOffset&&e.fullScreenOffset.length>0&&(u-=parseInt(e.fullScreenOffset,0))}f=u}else void 0!=e.minHeight&&f<e.minHeight&&(f=e.minHeight);e.c.closest(".rev_slider_wrapper").css({height:f})

        }catch(d){console.log("Failure at Presize of Slider:"+d)}
    };

    setREVStartSize();

                var tpj=jQuery;

    var revapi2;
    tpj(document).ready(function() {
        if(tpj("#rev_slider_2_1").revolution == undefined){
            revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_2_1");
        }else{
            revapi2 = tpj("#rev_slider_2_1").show().revolution({
                sliderType:"standard",
                sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
                dottedOverlay:"none",
                delay:9000,
                navigation: {
                    keyboardNavigation:"on",
                    keyboard_direction: "vertical",
                    mouseScrollNavigation:"on",
                        mouseScrollReverse:"default",
                    onHoverStop:"off",
                    touch:{
                        touchenabled:"on",
                        swipe_threshold: 75,
                        swipe_min_touches: 1,
                        swipe_direction: "vertical",
                        drag_block_vertical: false
                    }
                    ,
                    bullets: {
                        enable:true,
                        hide_onmobile:true,
                        hide_under:1024,
                        style:"zeus",
                        hide_onleave:false,
                        direction:"vertical",
                        h_align:"right",
                        v_align:"center",
                        h_offset:30,
                        v_offset:0,
                        space:5,
                        tmp:'<span class="tp-bullet-image"></span><span class="tp-bullet-imageoverlay"></span><span class="tp-bullet-title">{{title}}</span>'
                    }
                },
                responsiveLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                gridwidth:[1400,1240,778,480],
                gridheight:[868,768,960,720],
                lazyType:"none",
                shadow:0,
                spinner:"spinner2",
                stopLoop:"on",
                stopAfterLoops:0,
                stopAtSlide:1,
                shuffle:"off",
                autoHeight:"off",
                fullScreenAutoWidth:"on",
                fullScreenAlignForce:"off",
                fullScreenOffsetContainer: "",
                fullScreenOffset: "",
                disableProgressBar:"on",
                hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                debugMode:false,
                fallbacks: {
                    simplifyAll:"off",
                    nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                    disableFocusListener:false,
                }
            });
        }
    }); /*ready*/
</script>
```

I have search and didn’t find a proper answer. I know using resize() function but I don't know how to change the value in the script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you already got the width in the "i" variable, you can just create a short if statement like this in the variable offset:

```
e.fullScreenOffset = i > 1100 ? '0' : '125';
```

I don't know if you need it with the "px" at the end or just the number, also I don't know if that should be on the e.fullScreenOffsetContainer as well, anyways, hope this helped.

Leo.

Comment: "This works perfect" but I need that the value that gets e.fullScreenOffset be copied after down below in fullScreenOffset: ""
But I need to do it in php, I put this `var sl_Prueba = e.fullScreenOffset;` and then `echo 'fullScreenOffset:"'. esc_attr($sl_Prueba).'",'."\n";` in the php part but this doesn't transfer the value of the variable..

Comment: Well thats a different question that you could ask in stackoverflow, remember that you can't use the same variables in PHP as in JS, you have to either pass them as an ajax call to the php files, or only use them in JS and add them to a DOM element for later use. If you only want to call the variable within the JS code just call the variable again as you are needing it.

Comment: Just a small addition, if I have the value I want saved in a variable, how can I print that value on fullScreenOffset: " ",  ?